# MongoDB: Get the previous and next element in the embedded array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, slice

I have a database which has the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b8d72ab515211f3c161c4b"),
    "Transport_event_id" : 1,
    "Carrier_id" : 23,
    "Payload_id" : 0,
    "StartTime" : 214392.0,
    "EndTime" : 362707.0,
    "Move_events" : [ 
        {
            "Timestamp" : 214398,
            "x_pos" : 13,
            "y_pos" : 202
        },{
            "Timestamp" : 214845,
            "x_pos" : 12,
            "y_pos" : 202
        },{
            "Timestamp" : 216399,
            "x_pos" : 12,
            "y_pos" : 216
        },{
            "Timestamp" : 216842,
            "x_pos" : 11,
            "y_pos" : 216
        },{
            "Timestamp" : 219586,
            "x_pos" : 10,
            "y_pos" : 216
        }
    ]
}
```

I've made the following query which will return the next 2 Elements form a Array **after** a specific TimeStamp.

```
var cursor = db.Transport_eventBeta.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "StartTime": { "$lte": query_time } } },
    { "$match": { "EndTime": { "$gte": query_time } } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "Move_events": {
                "$let": {
                    "vars": {
                        "filtered": {
                            "$filter": {
                                "input": "$Move_events",
                                "as": "event",
                                "cond": { "$lte": ["$$event.Timestamp" , query_time] }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "in": { 
                        "$slice": [
                            "$Move_events",
                            {"$size": "$$filtered"},
                            2
                        ]
                    }  
                }
            },
            "Carrier_id": 1    
        }
    }
])
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   print(cursor.next());
}
```

What I need are the documents **befor and after** this specific TimeStamp.
Some kind of this:

```
"$slice": [
    "$Move_events",
    {"$size": "$$filtered"} - 1,
    2
]
```

But this doesn't work. How can I solve this problem? 2 separate queries are no option because of the duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query in 3.4.

The query will filter  `Move_events` to keep events with timestamp less than input `timestamp` followed by `$arrayElemAt` to get the `Move_events` after and before event.

```
db.Transport_eventBeta.aggregatee([
  {
    "$match": {
      "StartTime": {
        "$lte": query_time
      },
      "EndTime": {
        "$gte": query_time
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Move_events": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "filtered": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$Move_events",
                "as": "event",
                "cond": {
                  "$lte": [
                    "$$event.Timestamp",
                    query_time
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "in": [
            {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$Move_events",
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    {
                      "$size": "$$filtered"
                    },
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$Move_events",
                {
                  "$size": "$$filtered"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I was also trying to do something with `$indexOfArray`. The problem with this is, I don't know the exact time of these Elements. `$indexOfArray` for example needs the exact timestamp of 214845 to get the Event befor and behind.

[Tested Here](https://gist.github.com/iwaynee/5ad41b8db2260019eaf524b67910bd27)

btw: At `$substract` just 1 and not -1

Comment: If found the solution by combining our querys. 
https://gist.github.com/iwaynee/4321c696e08acfad5e4042b32081d4b9

I will accept your answer if you can correct your Query above :)